Build Dockerfile with Java and maven with CodeArtifact dependency
I'm trying to build my project using Docker, it has some Java REST APIs, I'm using Maven and Spring Boot on a multiservice architecture. I have a "slave" module called "common-utilities", it has all the generic entities and some Calendar utilities that I need and this module is used as dependency on all my other modules.
I was having a problem where Docker couldn't build since it doesn't find my own slave module as a dependency for the other one, since it's looking on Maven Central for it, after some searching I've found that I could manually copy this dependency's .jar to docker build's .m2 folder but, not happy with that solution. I then found that I could upload the slave module's .jar to a private repository, tried Nexus but since I'll use AWS soon, I moved to AWS Code Artifact.
Now the problem is, how to set the token from outside AWS's infrastructure that my settings.xml needs to download this dependency?

After searching a lot I've found a way to do this. I tried the RUN command but since it's execution can't save the result into an usable variable to be captured by settings.xml, I had to take another approach.
This is my Dockerfile:
###############################################################
# Build stage
# Maven image to build the application
FROM maven:3.9.6-amazoncorretto-17-al2023 AS build-stage

# Creating the directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
# Setting the working directory.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Adding the source code to the build stage.
ADD . /usr/src/app

# And here comes the Amazon configuration step!
RUN yum install aws-cli -y
RUN aws configure set aws_access_key_id 'YOUR KEY'
RUN aws configure set aws_secret_access_key 'YOUR SECRET ACCESS KEY'
RUN aws configure set aws_region 'YOUR REGION'
RUN aws configure set aws_output_format json

# Then I execute the command to get Code Artifact's token and save it into a file called "result" located in "./"
RUN aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain YOUR-DOMAIN --domain-owner YOUR-OWNER-ID --region YOUR-REGION --query authorizationToken --output text >> ./result

# So now I execute the maven install command passing the settings.xml WITH the property "token", which is a cat command to read from the file that has the token and to be used inside the XML file.
RUN mvn -Dtoken=${cat ./result} -s settings.xml install -U

###############################################################
# Production step. Now it's done, it works!
FROM openjdk:17-alpine AS production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /usr/src/app/target/*.jar my-api.jar
EXPOSE 8788
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod", "-Xmx256m", "-Xms128m", "-jar", "my-api.jar"]

And this is my settings.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.2.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.2.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.2.0.xsd">
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>domain-name</id>
    <username>aws</username>
    <password>${token}</password>
  </server>
</servers>

<profiles>
  <profile>
  <id>domain-name</id>
  <activation>
  <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
    <repositories>
      <repository>
           <id>domain-name</id>
           <url>repo-url</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
  </profile>
</profiles>
</settings>

I'm not sure if it's the right way but it works!! So I wanted to share this info with you guys cause I couldn't for the love of me find any info about how to do this.
